# FileNotFoundError:No such file or directory: ‘config/endpoints.yml’ while building Rasa using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to build rasa using docker with the given link and I keep getting this error while trying to run the command `sudo docker-compose up` on Ubuntu.

Please help me figure this out.

I have attached the images of the `docker-compose.yml` file and a picture of the docker images created and my folders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your error and other textual data as `code`, so it's easier to copy and read your problem.

Comment: From the information you have shared, I have attempted to provide an answer below. Let me know if this helped you, or perhaps what problem that you are facing - and I will try to assist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a misconfiguration in your docker-compose file there. The "command" section is not supposed to be used like that.

Here's an excerpt from the [docker-compose version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

> **command**
>
> Override the default command.
>
> `command: bundle exec thin -p 3000`
>
> The command can also be a list, in a manner similar to dockerfile:
>
> `command: ["bundle", "exec", "thin", "-p", "3000"]`

So in your case, you want to start by altering your docker-compose file to the following instead:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  rasa_core:
    image: rasa/rasa_core:latest
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - ./models/rasa_core:/app/models
      - .config:/app/config
    command: start --core models -c rest --endpoints config/endpoints.yml -u current/

  rasa_nlu:
    image: rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-spacy
    volumes:
      - ./models/rasa_nlu:/app/models
    command: start --path
```

Please remember that anything you put in the command in a docker-compose file, will overrride the `CMD` that is set in the `Dockerfile`, just like the command that is passed to `docker run` will override it.

And, remember that the `CMD` (or command, like here) will be appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` that is set in the image. So keep that in mind when you specify commands and entrypoints.

I notided, that the [rasa_core image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rasa/rasa_core) already has an `entrypoint.sh` script. It is configured like this in the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["start", "-d", "./dialogue"]
```

So what you are doing about the command is correct.

However, I think your volume mappings are also off, this is from the same [rasa_core `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
VOLUME ["/app/model", "/app/config", "/app/project"]
```

I appears that you need to update the volumes in the docker-compose file aswell (I removed the `s` from the `/app/models` mapping):

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  rasa_core:
    image: rasa/rasa_core:latest
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - ./models/rasa_core:/app/model
      - .config:/app/config
    command: start --core models -c rest --endpoints config/endpoints.yml -u current/

  rasa_nlu:
    image: rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-spacy
    volumes:
      - ./models/rasa_nlu:/app/models
    command: start --path
```

Finally, please check that you are mapping the correct directory to the `rasa_nlu` image. From the [Dockerfiles of the rasa_nlu project](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/tree/master/docker), it seems like it is not exposing any directory called `/app/models`. But just these:

```
VOLUME ["/app/projects", "/app/logs", "/app/data"]
```

Comment: Hi! Please let me know if the solution is workout out for you? Otherwise let me know what the problem is? Best regards